# symfony @Security annotations replacing each other instead of adding to each other

Tags: security, symfony, annotations

In Symfony2, I really like the @Security annotation to perform permissions checks.

However, when using this annotation, I come over a limitation which is you can't cumulate them.

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('organizer')")
 * @Security("is_granted('owner')")
 */
public function displayPlanningsAction($isModel = false)
{
```

or

```
 * @Security("is_granted('subscription_valid')")
 */
class PlanningController extends CustomBaseController
{
    /**
     * @Security("is_granted('owner')")
     */
    public function displayPlanningsAction($isModel = false)
    {
```

the two previous will only check for is_granted('owner'). That's kind of ok in the first example because I can just put an 'and' and write this in a single line, but it's really annoying for the second example because then I have to repeat for every method of the class.

Is there a simple way I could overcome this (without using the jmsextrasecuritybundle) ?

Comment: `@Security("is_granted('...')")` assumes there exists a hierarchy of permissions.  This means that it cannot be used for an OR check.  For example, `owner` might have all the permissions of `organizer` plus some, and `organizer` all the permissions of `subscription_valid` plus some.  Permission hierarchy is set in `security.yml`.  See [Firewall and Authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html).

Comment: I don't agree. Voters where introduced to do more complex authorization checks, which include not depending onnly on a strict role hierarchy. and here, my problem is not related to that, if the first result is ACCESS_GRANTED and the second ACCESS_ABSTAIN, the first won't be taken into consideration.